# Why does a range have to be mut in order to call `find` on it?

Tags: rust

I  want to find the first even number that is not 0. I'm not interested in mutating it, so I thought that this code above would give me an immutable option back:

```
fn main() {
    let first_ten = 0..10;
    let val = first_ten.find(|&n| (n % 2 == 0) && n > 0);
    println!("{}", val.unwrap());
}
```

Instead, I get the following error:

```
 --> src/main.rs:3:13
  |
2 |   let first_ten = 0..10;
  |       --------- consider changing this to `mut first_ten`
3 |   let val = first_ten.find(|&n| (n % 2 == 0) && n > 0);
  |             ^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow mutably
```

I found [this documentation page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find) and I see that the predicate is defined as:

```
P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool,
```

If I change the definition of `first_ten` to be `let mut first_ten = 0..10`, then the code works. Why does `first_ten` need to have `mut`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find` is `Iterator::find`, and that's defined as:

```
fn find<P>(&mut self, predicate: P) -> Option<Self::Item>
```

The definition of the predicate is irrelevant.  The important part is `&mut self`.

Why is it `&mut self` and not `&self`?  Because it's defined on `Iterator`, and the only base method on `Iterator` (*i.e.* that implementations must provide) is `next`, which is:

```
 fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>;
```

The only way you can get the next thing from an `Iterator` is to mutate it.  `find` doesn't have any choice.

The range has to be mutable because you're using it as an iterator, and iterators have to be mutable to be iterated, and searching an iterator requires iterating it.